# Should I have a cron job in a controller action?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

I was thinking what was best practice I need to run a cron job every 3 hours.

Should I move the job into a controller action and setup a route. Or should I create a job class instead and put it in the lib folder.

I was thinking it may be a benefit just to be able to make a HTTP request to start the job.
So I would have a HTTP request in a job class, which would be enqueued be resque scheduler  .

Answer (score 0):

In order to run cron jobs in my projects, I use the [clockwork](https://github.com/adamwiggins/clockwork) to schedule jobs. You can stick the clock.rb in your lib or app folder and just run the process. It's dead simple if you use `foreman` to manage your apps processes in development and you can definitely create an upstart file to start them up in production.